# how to handle redirection with Azure Login using JMeter

Tags: redirect, oauth-2.0, jmeter

how to resolve $Config={"iErrorDesc":0,"iErrorTitle":0,"strMainMessage":"We received a bad request.","strAdditionalMessage":"","strServiceExceptionMessage":"AADSTS90100: ctx parameter is empty or not valid.","strTraceId":"DynamicID","iErrorCode":90100,"iHttpErrorCode":400,"iViewId":1,"urlCancel": for login.microsoftonline.come/${loginID}/login API

I tried to record same flow in Neoload it worked fine but in Jmeter though the request is going same as in network Dev tools/NeoLoad the request seems to be throwing 400 Bad request.

I am expecting 302 as response code and in return it has to return Persistant cookies

Answer (score 0):

From the error message it seems that your `loginID` variable doesn't have its respective value which means that your correlation isn't working properly.

Revisit your [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) which extracts this `loginID` and amend it accordingly.

You can see all JMeter Variables which are defined either out-of-the-box or via Post-Processors using [Debug Sampler and View Results Tree listener combination](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter).

Also make sure to add [HTTP Cookie Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html) to your test plan if it's not there yet.

Comment: The previous API which are using LoginID as URL Parameters they seem to be working fine with the same response as comapred to Developer Tools

The boundaries for the correlation in Neoload are also same where the script is working fine(Able to Login without any issues in NeoLoad)

HTTP Cookie Manager is also added in the script.Can someone please provide inputs on this issue.